# Regular versus TC0

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, circuit-complexity, regular-language

According to [the Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:R#reg),
$\mathsf{Reg} \subseteq \mathsf{NC^1}$ and
we know that $\mathsf{Reg}$ cannot count so $\mathsf{TC^0} \not\subseteq \mathsf{Reg}$.
However it doesn't say if $\mathsf{Reg} \subseteq \mathsf{TC^0}$ or not. Since we don't know $\mathsf{NC^1}\not\subseteq\mathsf{TC^0}$ we also don't know $\mathsf{Reg} \not\subseteq \mathsf{TC^0}$.

> Is there a candidate for a problem in $\mathsf{Reg}$ that is not in $\mathsf{TC^0}$?
>
> Is there a conditional result implying that $\mathsf{Reg} \not\subseteq \mathsf{TC^0}$, e.g. if $\mathsf{NC^1} \not\subseteq \mathsf{TC^0}$ then $\mathsf{Reg} \not\subseteq \mathsf{TC^0}$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take $S_5$ as alphabet and 
$$L= \{ \sigma_1\cdots \sigma_n \in S_5^*\mid \sigma_1\circ\cdots\circ\sigma_n = \text{Id}\}$$
Barrington proved in [2] that $L$ is $\textrm{NC}^1$-complete for $\textrm{AC}^0$ reduction (and even with a more restrictive reduction actually).

In particular this shows that regular languages are not in $\textrm{TC}^0$ if $\textrm{TC}^0 \subsetneq \textrm{NC}^1$. By using semigroups theory (see the book of Straubing [1] for more details), we obtain that if $\textrm{ACC}^0$ is strictly in $\textrm{NC}^1$ then all regular languages are either $\textrm{NC}^1$-complete or $\textrm{ACC}^0$.

[1] Straubing, Howard (1994). "Finite automata, formal logic, and circuit complexity". Progress in Theoretical Computer Science. Basel: Birkhäuser. p. 8. ISBN 3-7643-3719-2.

[2] Barrington, David A. Mix (1989). "Bounded-Width Polynomial-Size Branching Programs Recognize Exactly Those Languages in NC1"

Comment: Furthermore, if ACC$^0$ is _not_ "strictly in NC$^1$ then all regular languages are" in ACC$^0$ anyway. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 15):

Regular languages with unsolvable syntactic monoids are $\mathrm{NC}^1$-complete (due to Barrington; this is the underlying reason behind the more commonly quoted result that  $\mathrm{NC}^1$ equals uniform width-5 branching programs). Thus, any such language is not in $\mathrm{TC}^0$ unless $\mathrm{TC}^0=\mathrm{NC}^1$.

My favorite $\mathrm{NC}^1$-complete regular expression is $((a|b)^3(ab^∗a|b))^∗$ (this is actually an encoding of $S_5$, as in C.P.'s answer).

Comment: what is a syntactic monoid?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_monoid

Comment: Warning of confusing terminology: in this context, a monoid is said to be unsolvable if it contains an unsolvable group as a *subsemigroup*, not necessarily as a submonoid.

Comment: My favourite NC^1-complete regular expression is $((a|b)^3(ab^*a|b))^*$ (this is actually an encoding of S_5, as in C.P.'s answer).

Comment: So basically asking if there is a DFA not implementable in TC0 or in other words is graph reachability in TC0 right?

Comment: Would you mind indicating how $((a|b)^3(ab^*a|b))^*$ encodes $S_5$?  Thanks!

Comment: Another example, less concise but easier to understand:
$$((a+b)(ab^*ab^*ab^*a+b))^*$$
the 'a' act as the cycle (1 2 3 4 5), the "b" act as the permutation (1 2), and those two group element are known to generate $S-5$.

Comment: @MichaelCadilhac: $a$ acts as $(1,2,3,4,5)$, and $b$ as $(1,2,3,4)$. These generate $S_5$ as $ba^{-1}$ is a transposition.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek 1) If $REG$ is complete for $NC^1$ then because $TC^0$ is in $NC^1$ it seems $REG$ can count. Is it correct? 2) If $TC^0\neq NC^1$ is $ACC^0\neq TC^0$ unconditionally or is it possible $ACC^0=TC^0\neq NC^1$ is still allowed?